# After updating NodeJS I get the following error: Failed to load gRPC binary module

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, grpc, firebase-admin

I am running a FireBase project after a warning that my current Node version (7.10) was not supported I updated it using npm and when running my server on localhost got the following error:

```
Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed 
for the current system
Expected directory: node-v51-linux-x64-glibc
Found: [node-v59-linux-x64-glibc]
This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current 
system
```

Reinstalling grpc whit this command did not helped:

```
sudo npm install -g grpc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, running:

```
sudo npm install -g grpc --allow-root --unsafe
```

solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to, package.json directory , and run

> sudo npm rebuild